# WSDL PHP function returns null while other function returns expected result

Tags: php, soap, null, wsdl

**Summary**

Here I'll list all steps I've taken to solve this problem as reference for others.

1.
PHP, stupidly enough, 'listens' to the input message of a function to define what function it should use. So give every one of your functions a different input message, even though it uses the same type or element. You may think this is quite some work for you to solve but it can be done like this:

```
<xsi:complexType name="UserCredentials">
<xsi:attribute name="customerID" type="xsi:int"/>
</xsi:complexType>

<xsi:element name="UserCredentials" type="types:UserCredentials"/>
<xsi:element name="UserCredentials1" type="types:UserCredentials"/>

<wsdl:message name="getCustomerCredentials">
 <wsdl:part name="body" element="types:UserCredentials"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCustomerCredentials1">
<wsdl:part name="body" element="types:UserCredentials1"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Next, Visual Studio was whining, I spend a couple of days figuring this stupidly idiotic simple thing out, just tell the program you have just set the objects property:

```
 UserCredentials.customerID = User.CustomerID;
 UserCredentials.customerIDSpecified = true;
```

And that's it. I can't believe it myself. I spend 1,5 weeks, solution is two steps, please give this guy who answered below some votes up.

**Update**

My input object is NOT begin parsed into XML.

//Fix:

You have to tell the program that the property is set like so:

```
UserCredentials.customerID = User.CustomerID;
UserCredentials.customerIDSpecified = true;
```

Fiddler shows this:

Input

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<UserCredentials2 xmlns="http://5.157.80.21/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl"/>   
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="types">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:PersoonArray/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:E‌​nvelope>
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

```
    public static List<Klant> GetAllPersonen()
    {
        List<Klant> list = new List<Klant>();

        WeGotchaService.Persoon[] servicePersonen = dpc.getAllPersoonData(UserCredentials);

        foreach (WeGotchaService.Persoon p in servicePersonen)
        {
            Klant k = new Klant(p);
            list.Add(k);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

**Update to comment below**

```
<xsi:complexType name="UserCredentials">
        <xsi:attribute name="customerID" type="xsi:int"/>       
    </xsi:complexType>
        <xsi:element name="UserCredentials" type="tns:UserCredentials" />
        <xsi:element name="UserCredentials2" type="tns:UserCredentials"/>

 <wsdl:message name="getCustomerCredentials">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="ns:UserCredentials"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCustomerCredentials2">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="ns:UserCredentials2"/>
</wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:operation name="getAllLessenData">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:getCustomerCredentials"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns2:LessenList"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllPersoonData">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:getCustomerCredentials2"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns3:PersoonList"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

This seems to work, except that it now returns a count=0 array in VS10

**Another Update**

In the comments someone posted a [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49169) to a bug report with PHP. The second last commenter claimed that he worked around this same issue I have by placing all the message defenitions in other files and included them in this main WSDL document. I tried this but it did not work, nothing changed.

**UPDATE:**

So I changed the order of the functions defined in the binding method, and figured out the following: only the first function defined in the binding area works, so in this case only my getAllLessenData works, because I put it above all the others. Does anyone see an error?

```
 <wsdl:binding name="DataBinding" type="tns:DataPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllLessenData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllPersoonData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllBetalingData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersoonLessenData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersoonBetalingenData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

**end of update**

I'm having a little problem with WSLD (again)

my getAllLessenData (and other functions) all return NULL while one function (getAllPersoonData) returns what is expected.

WSDL array defenitions:

```
<xsi:element name="PersoonArray">
            <xsi:complexType>
                <xsi:sequence>
                    <xsi:element name="Persoon" type="tns:Persoon" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsi:sequence>
            </xsi:complexType>
        </xsi:element>
        <xsi:element name="LessenArray">
            <xsi:complexType>
                <xsi:sequence>
                    <xsi:element name="Les" type="tns:Les" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsi:sequence>
            </xsi:complexType>
        </xsi:element>
```

WSDL complexType defenitions:

```
        <xsi:complexType name="Les">
            <xsi:attribute name="ID" type="xsi:int"/>
            // lots of stuff //
            <xsi:attribute name="Definitief" type="xsi:boolean"/>
        </xsi:complexType>
        <xsi:complexType name="Persoon">
            <xsi:attribute name="ID" type="xsi:int"/>
            <// lots of stuff //
            <xsi:attribute name="Laatste_keer_bewerkt" type="xsi:dateTime"/>
        </xsi:complexType>
```

WSDL message defenitions:

```
<wsdl:message name="getCustomerID">
    <wsdl:part name="CustomerID" type="xs:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PersoonList">
    <wsdl:part name="PersoonList" element="tns:PersoonArray"/>
</wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="LessenList">
    <wsdl:part name="LessenList" element="tns:LessenArray"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

WSDL portType defenition

```
 <wsdl:operation name="getAllPersoonData">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getCustomerID"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:PersoonList"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllLessenData">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getCustomerID"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:LessenList"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

WSDL Binding defention

```
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllPersoonData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/servicehandler.php" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllLessenData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/servicehandler.php" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

PHP function defenitions:

```
function getAllPersoonData($customer_ID)
{
   connectToDB();
//////////// yes I use mysqli now /////////////
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM personen WHERE Customer_ID='". $customer_ID ."'";

   $sql = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $result = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
  $row["Kosten_totaal"] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Kosten) FROM lessen WHERE Persoon_ID='". $row["ID"] ."'"))[0];
    $row["Totaal_betaald"] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM betalingen WHERE Persoon_ID='". $row["ID"] ."'"))[0];
    $lkbDatum = strtotime($row["Laatste_keer_bewerkt"]);
  $row["Laatste_keer_bewerkt"] = date("Y-m-d", $lkbDatum) . "T". date("H:i:s", $lkbDatum);
  $result[] = $row;             
}
mysql_close();

   return $result;
 }


 function getAllLessenData($customer_ID)
 {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE Customer_ID='". $customer_ID ."'";
//////////// yes I use mysqli now /////////////
connectToDB();

    $sql = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  $result[] = $row;
}
mysql_close();

    return $result;
 }

 $server = new SoapServer("wsdl_service.wsdl");
 $server->AddFunction("getAllPersoonData");
 $server->AddFunction("getAllBetalingData");
 $server->AddFunction("getPersoonBetalingData");
 $server->AddFunction("getAllLessenData");
 $server->AddFunction("getPersoonLessenData");
 $server->handle();
```

Test.php

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl", array("trace" => 1));

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

var_dump($client->getAllLessenData(1));

var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
```

which returns:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'PersoonArray getAllPersoonData(int $CustomerID)' (length=47)
  1 => string 'LessenArray getAllLessenData(int $CustomerID)' (length=45)
  2 => string 'BetalingenArray getAllBetalingData(int $CustomerID)' (length=51)
  3 => string 'LessenArray getPersoonLessenData(int $getCustomerID, int $getPersoonID)' (length=71)
  4 => string 'BetalingenArray getPersoonBetalingenData(int $getCustomerID, int $getPersoonID)' (length=79)
null
string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><CustomerID>1</CustomerID></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
' (length=195)
string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/weGotcha/servicehandler/wsdl_service.wsdl"><SOAP-ENV:Body> <ns1:PersoonArray><ns1:Persoon ID="1" Voornaam="xxxx" Achternaam="xxxx"  Adres="xxxx" Postcode="xxxx" Woonplaats="xxxx"  Email_adres="xxxx" Telefoonnummer="xxxx" Geboortedatum="0001-01-01" CBR_kandidaatnummer="12381233" Rijbewijs="2" Theorie_behaald="false" Theorie_po'... (length=3096)
```

There are rows in my database and calling getAllLessenData(1) directly from my servicehandler.php returns the expected results. however, in my test.php it simply returns NULL and the getLastResponse returns the results from getAllPersoonData(1).

Both function defenitions look the same for me, heck I copy-pasted most of it. I tried changing namespaces etc. google. but it didn't work. Any ideas?

If you need more info please respond.

Comment: Changing to RPC document type fixes this null return. But it breaks importing in Visual Studio

Comment: Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), not `mysql_*` functions, as they are deprecated. (P.S. - I should create a template for this, the mistake is so common :-)

Comment: Yes I heard it about 3 times now and I get annoyed by it. The only thing people can say is 'use MySQLi or PDO' they skip the question.

Comment: Well, that's the only thing I can help you with for this question, because I don't know SOAP or WSDL. And by the way, if you have heard it 3 times, why aren't you using MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: I am now but too lazy to update the question. ;)

Comment: FYI: The PHP Soap manual states there is a bug in PHP ("when defining several services in one wsdl file, and calling one of those services, you may always get the response for your first service"). More information: [PHP :: Bug #49169 :: SoapServer calls wrong function, although "SOAP action" header is correct](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49169).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm gonna look for solutions, single last comment: "Actually I circumvented the problem, by putting all the message definitions in separate files, which I then include in the schema-part of the wsdl."

Comment: I tried what was quoted in my last comment, placed every message defenition in a different namespace, resolved all potential name ambiguity but it did not work. Still the same error.

Comment: Does using `$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE Customer_ID='$customer_ID'";` work?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff All the functions work correctly if called directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 1: This may also have to do with the fact that `getAllPersoonData` and `getAllLessenData` have the same input signature, which means that, for document literal style web services, the endpoint won't be able to distinguish what kind of request you're actually making.  Try passing two different element names.

EDIT 2: Also, giving these messages different signatures would allow you to put `getPersoonID` within the type definition so that you only have one message part.  Right now, if you look in `Customer.wsdl` you have:

```
<wsdl:message name="getPersoonIDCustomerID">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="ns:UserCredentials"/>
    <wsdl:part name="getPersoonID" type="xs:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

You should not have more than one part in a document-literal message.

EDIT 3: If you don't want to define a new element for each function that you have, then you would have to switch to RPC literal, which wraps the request in the `wsdl:operation` name.  If this would fix everything except .NET, then you could try my [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796076/soap-requests-in-net/11796240#11796240) post on coaxing .NET into reading RPC-literal web services.

Comment: Yes, your edit1 did the trick within my test.php. But this way i'll have to define hundreds of different types and messages depending on how many functions I'm going to end up with. Any ideas for this? *Also i'm going to have to work with a lot of different CustomerCredential types in VS10. (which can be overcome with type2 as type1) EDIT2: this cannot be overcome with type1 as type2)

Comment: You would have to use RPC literal in order for the SOAP message to get wrapped in the operation name.  I'll put that in the answer, too.

Comment: I'm working something out right now, I'll post in 2 minutes.

EDIT: this seems to work. Except that it now returns an empty array (count=0) in visual studio.

  <xsi:complexType name="UserCredentials">
   <xsi:attribute name="customerID" type="xsi:int"/>  
  </xsi:complexType>
   <xsi:element name="UserCredentials" type="tns:UserCredentials" />
   <xsi:element name="UserCredentials2" type="tns:UserCredentials"/>

<wsdl:operation name="getAllLessenData">
   <wsdl:input message="ns:getCustomerCredentials*N*"/>
   <wsdl:output message="ns2:LessenList"/>
  </wsdl:operation>

Comment: Code is weird?  You mean that VS10 returns an empty array?  What does it do from your PHP test?  If one works and not the other, compare the XML that's sent over the wire using WireShark.

Comment: No I meant in my comment so I placed it above in my post. I'll try WireShar (already have fiddler) but I'm working on a localhost so I'm gonna have to port it all to my server.

Comment: Anything that captures the XML will do.  Just post what the request and response look like for PHP vs. .NET.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15346/discussion-between-davidfmatheson-and-amazingdreams)

Comment: The methods `getPersoonLessenData` and `getPersoonBetalingenData' may still have confusing method signatures.

Comment: Weird how a parameter defines the function used  :-$

Comment: Can you put the accessible service endpoint in the question for others to play with?

Comment: In fiddler I see a request connection but no return connection. Any ideas? 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="types"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:PersoonArray/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Comment: Which call are you trying to make?  Looks like a server-side problem at this point.  You can make the individual calls properly from the client-side, correct?  It sends different messages for each method invocation.  Now you just have to debug what the server does with them.